# Pandas dataframe merge skips rows?

Tags: python, pandas

This seems odd.

There's one data frame (df_ceremonies):

```
    Year    Ceremony_Date
0   1927/28 May 16, 1929
1   1928/29 April 3, 1930
2   1929/30 November 5, 1930
3   1930/31 November 10, 1931
4   1931/32 November 18, 1932
5   1932/33 March 16, 1934
6   1934    February 27, 1935
7   1935    March 5, 1936
```

Here's the second df:

```
    Year       Ceremony Award   Winner  Name                Film
0   1927/1928   1       Actor   NaN     Richard Barthelmess The Noose
1   1927/1928   1       Actor   1.0     Emil Jannings       The Last Command
2   1927/1928   1       Actress NaN     Louise Dresser      A Ship Comes In
3   1927/1928   1       Actress 1.0     Janet Gaynor        7th Heaven
4   1927/1928   1       Actress NaN     Gloria Swanson      Sadie Thompson
```

Here's the command & result.  Notice how the years don't join until 1934, thus skipping 1927/1928, etc. They are all of the object data type. Why so?

```
df_revised = pd.merge(df, df_ceremonies, on='Year')

    Year    Ceremony    Award   Winner  Name            Film          Ceremony_Date
0   1934    7          Actor    1.0     Clark Gable     It Happened One Night   February 27, 1935
1   1934    7          Actor    NaN     Frank Morgan    The Affairs of Cellini  February 27, 1935
2   1934    7          Actor    NaN     William Powell  The Thin Man    February 27, 1935
3   1934    7         Actress   1.0     Claudette Colbert   It Happened One Night   February 27, 1935
4   1934    7         Actress   NaN     Bette Davis      Of Human Bondage   February 27, 1935
```

Comment: That is quite normal when comparing objects (strings): `'1927/28' != '1927/1928'` isn't it?

Comment: A column can be of object type but individual cells can still be of different fundamental types.  Also these strings are not the same:  '1927/28' != '1927/1928'

Comment: Yes, "close only counts in horseshoes and hand grenades." I can't believe I didn't see  that. Much appreciated. A few changes are in order.